# How to stop default music player while I'm running my music app

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a music player app.

If in background the default music player is running and if I use my app to play music, both runs simultaneously.

Is there a way to stop background music player.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app takes the audio focus, that should cause the current player to stop. Details are at http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html#RequestFocus

There's a bunch of other niceties; you probably want to register yourself as the media button event receiver, so that it's your app that stops and starts playing. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html for details on that.

Comment: thanks, I've made the default android player stop. but how to stop my app on focus loss :)... question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839742/how-to-resgister-my-musicplayer-app-to-onaudiofocuschangelistener)

Answer (score -2):

In your app (music player) 
You want to access another process

typically 
JVM will not give u this permission over system processes

BUT
you can make it by using that trick

1. develop (..exe) [by c OR c++ OR c#] that kill any music player is running
   thats because those langs can handle system processes
2. in your app calling this exe file (run it)

That is the trick

Comment: The question is tagged with android, so answers talking about the dalvik virtual machine and the associated runtime environment (rather than the JVM on Windows) are likely to be more useful.

Comment: Sorry
I seen a Java tag But did NOT note android tag